# SQL CASE WHEN won't meet condition

Tags: mysql, sql, case

```
select salary as SecondHighestSalary
from Employee
where salary = case 
    when (select count(*)
         from Employee) <= 1 then null
    when (
        select count(*)
        from Employee
    ) > 1 then (
        select salary
        from (select salary
              from Employee
              order by salary desc
              limit 2
        ) as two_highest_salary_table
        order by salary asc
        limit 1
    )
    end;
```

This is a solution to one of the leetcode problem. It is asking me to output the second highest salary from the table and if there are no second highest salary then the output should be null.

The above is my solution. I used case and when syntax but the problem is that even when the table only has 1 row, it doesn't output a table with a NULL value but it just output a table w nothing in it.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you only have a single row n your table, your condition is actually `where salary = null` this will never be true. Thus none of your rows is meeting the condition and so no row is returned ...

Comment: Seems you got a little confused :-) `select count(*) from Employee` counts all rows in the employee table. But who cares how many rows are in that table? It has nothing to do with the task. But what you do is: For every row in the table check whether there is a row in the table. Well, there is obviously, otherwise you wouldn't be able to ask the question (no row = no where clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler, as you thought, a simole SELECT with LOT and OFFSET is enough

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Employee (salary DECIMAL(10,2))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(10000.1)
> ```

> ```
> select salary
>               from Employee
>               order by salary desc
>               limit 1,2
> ```

> ```
> | salary |
> | -----: |
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(20000.2)
> ```

> ```
> select salary
>               from Employee
>               order by salary desc
>               limit 1,2
> ```

> ```
> |   salary |
> | -------: |
> | 10000.10 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d0da63af77952019b6c4dd093b05bd1)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating a little.

Try :

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) as Salary
From Employee1 
WHERE Salary < ( SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Employee1);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c2711fa4fe6429fc7319aec67fd6987)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to always return a row with NULL if there's no qualifying second-highest value you need to outer join to a source row - this will allow you to return all columns if required.

```
select Salary
from
(select 2 as s) choice
left join (
  select salary, dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) rnk
  from Employee
)s on  s.rnk = s;
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9240b69c81ee4e8d9db30577b2191965)